# Can a Backbone model contains its own Collection

Tags: backbone.js

Can a Backbone model contains a collection of its own type?

```
component = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults:{
'name' : 'Name1',
'subcomponents' :Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: component 
});
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

You can have a complex Backbone model graph, that I advise you to maintain with something like [Backbone Relational](http://backbonerelational.org/) or similar libs.

Comment: Could you please give a bit more details.I am already using nested Backbone.nestedtypes could could not succeed.